# Cannot access Vue data set within mounted via ajax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue2. I am getting json data via ajax in my mounted method. I then set that data to a data variable expecting to be able to access it from other methods outside of mounted, but all I get is an empty observable.

Any suggestions/advice? Thanks for the help.

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: function () {
    return {
        allJson: []
    };
},
methods: {
    updateTableData:  function(isActive) {
        // cannot access this.allJson here
    }
},
mounted: function() {
    $.getJSON(Routes.USERS_GET_JSON, function(json) {
        this.allJson = json;
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used jQuery in a long, long time, but if I remember correctly you need to explicitly declare the context of `this` if you wish to use it within the callback, else you get something unexpected. However, I don't know if `$.getJSON` supports it even though it's a wrapper. So you can try the following:

```
$.getJSON(Routes.USERS_GET_JSON, function(json) {
    this.allJson = json;
}, {
    context: this
})
```

Or you can use `.bind` off of the function to scope `this`

```
$.getJSON(Routes.USERS_GET_JSON, function(json) {
    this.allJson = json
}.bind(this))
```

Or if you're tranpsiling down with babel (which you probably are) you can use `fat arrow` syntax:

```
$.getJSON(Routes.USERS_GET_JSON)
    .done( (json) => {
        this.allJson = json
    })
```

Or you can just alias `this` before the `$.getJSON`

```
let _self = this

 $.getJSON(Routes.USERS_GET_JSON, function(json) {
    _self.allJson = json
 })
```

Comment: The bind and fat arrow solutions worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `this` is not bound to your vue instance inside the callback function. Try the following

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: function () {
    return {
        allJson: []
    };
},
methods: {
    updateTableData:  function(isActive) {
        // cannot access this.allJson here
    }
},
mounted: function() {
    const self = this;
    $.getJSON(Routes.USERS_GET_JSON, function(json) {
        self.allJson = json;
    });
}
});
```

Comment: This solution works as well, and I thought I had tried it. What I notice is that when accessing the data inside my updateTableData() method, I cannot access "this.allJson" because I get the empty observable, but if I access 'this.allJson.users" then I get all the users I would expect. Thanks for posting this solution.

Comment: No problem. Glad things worked out for you in the end :)