# How to get Vue props and data fetched from within an AJAX call in the mounted() and created() hooks

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, vuejs2, fetch, vue-props

I'm just trying to set data got it from an AJAX call using the built-in `fetch()` method into a data variable `courts` of my Vue component (I'm using Vue2).

I know that when you are into the `fetch()` method, the context of keyword `this` can change. However, if I bind the variable `courts` as a prop to my child component **it gets rendered into the HTML**, but still I cannot access to the prop from, for instances, the `created()` and `mounted()` lifecycle hooks.

I've already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569654/cannot-access-vue-data-set-within-mounted-via-ajax) which points out the issue about the keyword `this`.

Because of the asynchronous workflow of JavaScript, I also check if I obtain the data by using the `setTimeout()` method which I do, but not **in my child component** as a prop.

I have Babel loaded from Webpack and I was trying to sort it out with an `async await` function, with no luck.

#### App.vue (Parent Component)

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <court-map v-bind:items="courts"></court-map>
        <navbar v-bind:items="courts"></navbar>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import CourtMap from './components/CourtMap.vue';
    import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            'navbar': Navbar,
            'court-map': CourtMap
        },
        data() {
            return {
                courts: [],
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getCourts();
        },
        methods: {
            getCourts() {
                let _self = this;
                fetch('/api/courts', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    _self.courts = data; // With alias
                    this.courts = data;
                    console.log(_self.courts); // Shows my data
                })
                    .catch(error => console.error(error));

                console.log(_self.courts); // No longer shows my data
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log(_self.courts); // Shows my data
                    console.log(this.courts); // Undefined
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I also use `this.$props.items` to access to my prop but it gives me an empty array.

#### CourtMap.vue (Child Component)

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to use `this` within the index of the variable.

```
<template>
    <div class="map-viewer">
        <div class="esri-widget">
            <camera-info v-bind:camera="camera"></camera-info>
        </div>
        <div>{{ items }}</div> // Renders the prop with the right data
        <div id="viewMap"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

    export default {
        components: {
            'camera-info': CameraInfo
        },
        props: {
            items: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                firstIndex: 0,
                camera: {
                    position: {
                        longitude: this.items[this.firstIndex].longitude, // Return this is not defined
                        latitude: this.items[this.firstIndex].latitude // Return this is not defined
                    },
                    tilt: 0,
                    heading: 0
                },
            }
        },
        created() {
        },
        methods: {
            createMap() {
               // Some function here
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.items); // Doesn't show the data
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(this.items); // Doesn't show the data too
            }, 3000);
            this.createMap();
        },
    }
</script>
```

#### Index.js (Where I start my Vue App)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

I guess this is something a novice has to get through, but for that reason I want to know which pattern I have to follow every time I want to acces to a fetched data in Vue. I don't see now how to proceed.

Thanks beforehand for taking your time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clear a few things up.

`this` doesn't just randomly change. It changes when you enter a new function. Using an alias like `self` was historically a way of avoiding this problem but in your case you're using arrow functions. An arrow function won't change the `this` value from the surrounding scope.

Now let's look at why this doesn't work:

```js
mounted () {
    console.log(this.items); // Doesn't show the data
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(this.items); // Doesn't show the data too
    }, 3000);
```

The first time it tries to access `this.items` is too soon. The asynchronous `fetch` won't have completed yet.

The second time, inside the `setTimeout`, we've got a new function, so the `this` value changes. Using an arrow function should show the correct data:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.items);
}, 3000);
```

Assuming, of course, that the data loads within 3 seconds.

Of course a timer isn't the correct way to handle this.

The simplest option is to avoid creating the child components until the data is available:

```html
<court-map v-if="courts.length" :items="courts"></court-map>
```

The `v-if` will prevent the component being created until there are entries in the array. Doing it this way ensures the `created` and `mounted` hooks won't be run until the `courts` are ready to be passed as `items`.

Perhaps an empty array isn't the best choice of initial value here as it's difficult to tell that apart from an empty array returned by the server. If instead we use a `null` value initially that gets a bit simpler.

```js
data() {
    return {
        courts: null
    }
},
```

with:

```html
<court-map v-if="courts" :items="courts"></court-map>
```

Other code that uses `courts` may need adjusting accordingly.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `v-if` to delay the creation of the children then you could use `watch` within the child to wait for when `items` changes. You can then trigger any actions that needs to occur.

A further note on why this line doesn't work:

```js
longitude: this.items[firstIndex].longitude
```

So the first problem is that `this.items` won't have loaded yet (as covered above). The second problem will be that `firstIndex` isn't defined. The `firstIndex: 0` a few lines above it is irrelevant. `this.items[firstIndex]` is trying to use a local variable called `firstIndex` and that doesn't exist.

Without knowing more it's difficult to say but `position` might be better implemented as a computed property.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer, I appreciate this. Let me ask you something. Theoretically the `mounted()` triggers when the component it is mounted into the DOM or at least this is what I understand in the [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) but does not guarantee that **the child components have been mounted too**, which is not my case because I want the data to be rendered in the same component. So, why is displaying the data into the template but not in my `mounted()` lifecycle hook? I would try using `this.$nextTick()` but I will come across with the issue about the keyword `this`.

Comment: @SalvaLópez The `mounted` hook is only called when a component first renders. Subsequent rendering will trigger the `updated` hook instead. When your template first runs the array is empty. Once the data loads from the server the template will run again, showing the correct values. This may all happen so quickly that you don't even notice the initial render. Using `$nextTick` won't help. That will wait until after rendering is complete but it won't wait for the asynchronous data loading. You need to learn how `this` works rather than avoiding it: arrow functions are your friend.